# How to extract a sublist from another list based on value with indices

Tags: python, list

I need to get a sublist called `invalids` from another list called `opened_list` that pulls the records containing the value `12` along with their index in the list.
I have tried the below code

```
x = opened_list
print (x.index(-1))
```

I want the output to be something like

- 25  12
- 32  12
- 74  12

Comment: What have you tried? Please show the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a=[1,12,3,4,12,5,12]                                                    
b=[]                                                                    
for idx,item in enumerate(a): 
    if item==12: b.append((idx,item)) 
print(b)
```

prints:   [(1, 12), (4, 12), (6, 12)]